# How to find a value in a row/column and return its column/row number to store as a variable?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am writing a code that will ask a series of prompts to the user.  The answers to the prompts are then used to select a specific range and write information into said range.  Question 1 will ask the user for some value (a time) that is found in column 1 of my sheet "Class".  Question 2 will ask for a value found in row 2 of my sheet.  Question 3 asks how many cells tall the range will be, and question 4 asks what information should be stored in the selected range.

I am trying to set up 2 for loops.  One loop will check for the answer to question 1 (answer1) against values from column 1 between rows 3 and 53.  Once it finds a match, I want it to return the row number of the matching value.  The second loop will check for the answer to question 2 (answer2) in row 2 and return the column number where the value was found.  I want the information to be stored into variables rowNo and colNo, so that: sheet.getRange(rowNo, colNo, answer3, 1).setValue(answer4).

I am having a lot of difficulty actually creating the loop.  Whenever I run the script, rowNo is returned as 3 and colNo is returned as 1.  I have been looking around on stack overflow for quite some time, but I have not found a script that I can succesfully modify to store the information I'm looking for as a variable to use later in the function.

To sum it up:

- **I need a loop to check for a value in a range and return its ROW number.**
- **I need a loop to check for a value in a range and return its COLUMN number.**

This is what I have tried.

```html
function prompts()  {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Class');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var maxCol = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  
  //Prompts
  var question1 = ui.prompt(
    'This is question 1.',
    'Enter class start time.',
    ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  
  var question2 = ui.prompt(
    'This is question 2.',
    'Enter class name.',
    ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  
  var question3 = ui.prompt(
    'This is question 3.',
    'How many 15 minute blocks make up the class?',
    ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  
  var question4 = ui.prompt(
    'This is question 4.',
    'Enter coach name here.',
    ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  
  //cancel prompt
  var cancel = ui.alert('Canceled');
  //finished prompt
  var finished = ui.alert('Finished');

  
  
  
  //Process question1 response
  var button1 = question1.getSelectedButton();
  var answer1 = question1.getResponseText();
  
  if(button1 == ui.Button.OK)  {
    //User clicked "OK"
    //Ask question 2
    var button2 = question2.getSelectedButton();
    var answer2 = question2.getResponseText();
    
    if(button2 == ui.Button.OK)  {
      //User clicked "OK"
      //Ask question 3
      var button3 = question3.getSelectedButton();
      var answer3 = question3.getResponseText();
      
      if(button3 == ui.Button.OK)  {
        //User clicked "OK"
        //ask question 4
        var button4 = question4.getSelectedButton();
        var answer4 = question4.getResponseText();
        
        if(button4 == ui.Button.OK)  {
          //User clicked "OK"
          //Find matching value of answer 1 in column 1 of sheet "Class" and return its row number in var = rowNo
          var range1 = sheet.getRange(3,1,50,1);
          var values1 = range1.getValues();
          var row = [];
          for (var i = 3; i<=53; i++)  {
            if(values1[i] == answer1)  {
              row.push(i);
            }
          }
          var rowNo = Number(row)+Number(range1.getRow());
          //Find matching value of answer 2 in row 2 of sheet "Class" and return its column number in var = colNo
          var range2 = sheet.getRange(2,1,1,maxCol);
          var values2 = range2.getValues();
          var col = [];
          for (var j = 1; j<=maxCol; j++)  {
            if(values2[j] == answer2)  {
              col.push(j);
            }
          }
          var colNo = Number(row)+Number(range1.getColumn());
          //Set value to the range as the answer to question 4
          sheet.getRange(rowNo, colNo, answer3, 1).setValue(answer4);
        

          
        } else if (button4 == ui.Button.CANCEL)  {
          //User clicked "CANCEL"
          cancel;
        } else if (button4 == ui.Button.CLOSE)  {
          //user clicked "CLOSE"
          cancel;
        }
      } else if (button3 == ui.Button.CANCEL)  {
        //User clicked "CANCEL"
        cancel;
      } else if (button3 == ui.Button.CLOSE)  {
        //user clicked "CLOSE"
        cancel;
      
    } else if (button2 == ui.Button.CANCEL)  {
      //User clicked "Cancel"
      cancel;
    } else if (button2 == ui.Button.CLOSE)  {
      //User clicked X
      cancel;
    }
    
    
  } else if (button1 == ui.Button.CANCEL)  {
    //User clicked "Cancel"
    cancel;
  } else if (button1 == ui.Button.CLOSE)  {
    //user clicked X
    cancel;
  }
 }
}
```

I would appreciate any help anyone can give me!

Also, as a side note, whenever the script finishes, it will show me both my cancel and finished prompts, if someone knows a solution to that as well.

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your question, can I ask you about the following 3 questions? 1. Can you provide the sample answers for question1 to question4? 2. Can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your current issue? 3. Can I ask you about the detail of `Also, as a side note, whenever the script finishes, it will show me both my cancel and finished prompts, if someone knows a solution to that as well.`?

Comment: Question 1 asks for a time.  All the values in column 1, starting in row 3, are 15 minute increments starting at 8:00 AM.  A sample answer to question 1 could be "10:15 AM".  Question 2 asks for the name of a class (the sheet's purpose is to schedule gymnastics classes), for example, "Level 1".  The class names are found in row 2.  Question 3 is asking how long the class is, by 15 minute increments, so someone would answer "4" if the class were an hour long.  Question 3 is the name of the person who will be teaching the class, say "Ryan".

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, the answers for qustion1 to question4 are `10:15 AM`, `Level 1`, `4` and `Ryan`, respectively. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yeo.  That would be correct.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I could understand about my question 1. About my questions 2 and 3, can I ask you about them?

Comment: Yes.  I am working on getting a link to my spreadsheet to answer your second question.  As to the third, I created two alerts to notify me if the script finished (I answered all four prompts), or if it was canceled at some point during the process.  However, whenever I answer all four questions, it will show me both my canceled alert and my finished alert instead of just finished.  I hope that makes some sense.

Comment: here is a link to the copy of my spreadsheet.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RJVmCimFh24NbAlENJvH5pT3zRq_KLJmFdEWqUN_Fo8/copy#gid=1368043778

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing the sample Spreadsheet. I think that I could understand about your replying. When I could find the reason of your issue, I would like to propose the modification points. When you give me a time to do, I'm glad.

Comment: I'll attach an image shortly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221759/discussion-between-quincey-frewin-and-tanaike).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- There are 2 questions in  your question.

  1. You want to retrieve the row number and column number by searching the values of "Class" sheet from inputted answers.
  2. You want to know about the reason of `I created two alerts to notify me if the script finished (I answered all four prompts), or if it was canceled at some point during the process. However, whenever I answer all four questions, it will show me both my canceled alert and my finished alert instead of just finished.`.

#### Modification points:

- `getValues()` returns 2 dimensional array. And in your script, `var row = [];` and `var col = [];` are the array.
- When the values of column "A" is the date object, the values retrieved with `getValues()` are also the date object.

  - The array and string are compared. By this, `row` and `col` are `[]`. I think that this might be the reason of issue of your 1st question.
- I thought that TextFinder might be suitable for your situation.
- In your script, `var cancel = ui.alert('Canceled');` and `var finished = ui.alert('Finished');` are used. In this case, these are directly run.

  - I think that this is the reason of issue of your 2nd question.
  - For example, when you want to run the script of `var cancel = ui.alert('Canceled');` by `cancel`, how about modifying it to `var cancel = () => ui.alert('Canceled');` and `cancel();`. By this, when `cancel();` is run, `var cancel = () => ui.alert('Canceled');` is run.
- I thought that in your case, when each answers are put in an array, the script might be simple.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function prompts()  {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Class');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var maxCol = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  
  // I modified below script.
  const questions = [
    {title: 'This is question 1.', prompt: 'Enter class start time.'},
    {title: 'This is question 2.', prompt: 'Enter class name.'},
    {title: 'This is question 3.', prompt: 'How many 15 minute blocks make up the class?'},
    {title: 'This is question 4.', prompt: 'Enter coach name here.'},
  ];
  const answers = questions.map(({title, prompt}) => {
    const res = ui.prompt(title, prompt, ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    return {button: res.getSelectedButton(), answer: res.getResponseText()};
  });
  if (answers.some(({button}) => button != ui.Button.OK)) {
    ui.alert('Canceled');
    return;
  }
  if (answers.some(({answer}) => answer.toString() == "")) {
    ui.alert('No inputted value.');
    return;
  }
  
  //Find matching value of answer 1 in column 1 of sheet "Class" and return its row number in var = rowNo
  const ranges1 = sheet.getRange(3,1,50,1).createTextFinder(answers[0].answer).matchEntireCell(true).findAll();

  //Find matching value of answer 2 in row 2 of sheet "Class" and return its column number in var = colNo
  const ranges2 = sheet.getRange(2,1,1,maxCol).createTextFinder(answers[1].answer).matchEntireCell(true).findAll();
  
  //Set value to the range as the answer to question 4
  if (ranges1.length > 0 && ranges2.length > 0) {
    var rowNo = ranges1[0].getRow();
    var colNo = ranges2[0].getColumn();
    sheet.getRange(rowNo, colNo, answers[2].answer, 1).setValue(answers[3].answer);
  } else {
    ui.alert('Values were not found.');
  }
  
//  ui.alert('Finished');  // I'm not sure whether you want this line.
}
```

#### References:

- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)
- [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)